# How to make calculations from reference frame of one of the twins in a completely symmetrical twin paradox?

Tags: special-relativity, relativity

Over the years, so many questions have been posted on twin paradox. But, I am trying to understand how to use equations correctly.

Consider a completely symmetrical version of the paradox.

There are twins Jack and Jill.

------------- Relative to some inertial frame S---------------

When Jack and Jill are together at the origin of S (let us call the origin as O), they synchronize their clock to S clock. All three clocks are set to 0.

Jack moves to left at speed 0.5c and Jill moves to right at speed 0.5c

Jack goes to a star P and turns and continues moving at 0.5c

Jill goes to a star Q and turns and continues moving at 0.5c

P and Q are at rest relative to S.

OP = OQ = 5 light years (ly) as measured in frame S.

---

P and Q take negligible time (as measured by their own clocks) in turning.

We know that when they meet again at origin, their clock readings should be equal. It is easy to show, by calculations, they will be equal in S frame. Can we prove they will be equal in Jack's frame?

Here is my attempt.

-------------------- In Jack's frame ---------------------

Length contraction is by a factor of 0.866 (because speed is 0.5c)

OP = OQ = (5)(0.866) = 4.33 ly (due to length contraction)

Event 1: Jack and Jill are at O

```
    Their clocks show 0.
```

Event 2: Jack is at star P

```
    Jack's clock reading = 4.33/0.5 = 8.66 years

    Jill's velocity = (1/1.25)c = 0.8c (by velocity addition)

    Jill's position = (0.8) (8.66) = 6.928 ly

    Q's position = 8.66 ly

    Therefore, Jill has still not reached Q. 

    She is at a distance 8.66 - 6.928 = 1.732 ly from Q.

    Since Jill's velocity is 0.8c, time dilation factor will be 0.6

    Jill's clock reading = (8.66)(0.6) = 5.196 years
```

Event 3: Jack has turned

```
    Jack's clock reading = 8.66 years

    How to calculate Jill's clock reading?

    Jill's position = 6.928 ly (as in Event 2)

    Jill's position is same as it was before Jack turned.

    But, by now she has already gone to Q and turned.

    At event 2, she was at 1.732 ly from Q. 

    She has, since event 2, covered a distance of (1.732)(2) = 3.464 ly

    Jill's clock reading has advanced by 3.464/0.5 = 6.928 years

    Jill's clock reading at event 2 was 5.196 years

    Jill's clock reading now = 5.196 + 6.928 = 12.124 years
```

Event 4: Jack is at O

```
    Jack's clock reading = 8.66 + 8.66 = 17.32 years

    When Jack turned (Event 3), Jill was at 6.928 ly from him and

    she was coming towards him at speed 0.8c

    Jill's position = 6.928 - (0.8)(8.66) = 0

    Therefore, Jill has also reached O.

    Since event 3, Jack's clock advanced by 8.66 years.

    By time dilation, Jill's clock advanced by (8.66)(0.6) = 5.196 years

    At event 3, Jill's clock reading was 12.124 years

    Jill's clock reading now = 12.124 + 5.196 = 17.32 years
```

---

When Jack comes back to starting point, he finds that Jill also has come back. He finds that both his and Jill's clock read 17.32 years. But, I am not sure if my calculations are correct. I am particularly doubtful about the way I calculated Jill's clock reading at Event 3.

Comment: Assume that gravitational field is negligible throughout the journeys of the twins.

Comment: Jack and Jill’s frames are non inertial. There is no standard definition for non inertial frames. You will need to be more specific, e.g. by writing down the complete transformations from S to their frames.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is neglecting the most important part of Jake's journey — acceleration around $P$. I made an animation for you which shows the trajectories of Jake and Jill, frame of reference of Jake and the the Jill's position simultaneous in Jake's frame of reference.

[image]

We see that during Jake's acceleration, he sees very fast movement of Jill. If we plot distance and the velocity of Jill, we will see that Jill moves faster than light.

[image]

So it's very hard to calculate the time of Jill in Jake's coordinate system as it's no longer just integration of time dilation.

Comment: You are wanting your animation to be in Jake's frame of reference?

Comment: Something should be wrong here, is not true that in SR no object can move faster than light in any reference frame, including non-inertial ones?

Comment: Wolphram Jonny: No.  Imagine looking at Alpha Centauri, which is approx 4 ly away, if I remember correctly.  Now rotate yourself about an axis perpendicular to the ray to it w/ a period of 1 sec.  From your rotating frame, Alpha Centauri will move in a circle w/ circumference of approx 24 ly in 1 sec.

Comment: @WRSomsky true, thanks

Comment: Yes, Jack finds a very fast movement of Jill but he finds that Jill is still at the same position though now she is coming closer to him. This means, during his turn-around, Jack finds Jill's average velocity to be 0 but average speed to be almost infinite.

Comment: To add to what I wrote above - But how will Jack even calculate Jill's average speed? From his perspective, Jill did not move at all. She remained in the same position, but turned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work *entirely* in Jack's frame, including the time during turn-around, you have to realize that it's *not* an inertial reference frame, and you can't rely on SR alone.  At the turn-around, Jack will feel an apparent gravitational force, pulling in the direction away from where Jill's ship is.  While this occurs Jack is deep in a gravitational well relative to Jill (from his frame's point of view), and from GR there will be a factor slowing his clock relative to Jill's. This is strong enough to make Jill's clock rush forward during this time, just enough so that when they meet again, they will both have measured the same proper time.

Comment: But if only one twin turns, then I can make calculations in that twin's frame using SR alone. I find the clock reading of the other twin using Lorentz transformation and I get the expected result. But I am not sure if only result is correct or the method also is correct. Problem arises when both twins turn.

Comment: Even then, if you're going to be doing things from the point of view of the turn-around twin, you have to do some special jiggery pokery during the turn around. You can do it by calculating the shifting-simultanety but you have to assume that moving twin *knows* that he is the moving one. \

Answer (score 0):

The first part, showing Jack's trip to star P is OK. We can call frame A that velocity to the left at 0.5c (original Jack frame). And Frame B, the velocity to right at 0.5c (original Jill frame).

Keeping all the calculations in frame A, after Jack's turn he is now going right at 0.8c. He will arrive at earth at the interception of 2 lines: x = -0.5t (velocity of earth) and x = -0.8(t - 8.66) (velocity of Jack's ship). The coordinates of the arrival are: x = 11.55 ly and t = 23.09 y.

In order to calculate the corresponding time at earth, we use Lorentz transformation:

$t_e = (1/0.866)(23.09 - 0.5*11.55) = 20 y$ as expected.

For the corresponding time at Jack's ship: 
$t_{ja} = 8.66 + (1/0.6)((23.09 - 8.66) - 0.8*11.55) = 17.3 y$

For Jill's trip, he is initially going right at 0.8c, while star Q is going right at 0.5c. The coordinates are the interception of the lines: $x = -0.8t$ and $x+4.33 = -0.5t$, resulting in $t = 14.43$ and $x = -11.55$.

After turning back, Jill's ship is at rest in frame A, while the earth is going to him at 0.5c. The return point is the interception of lines: $x = -11.55$ and $x = -0.5t$ resulting in x = -11.55 and t = 23.09.

The time, measured by Jill's clock is: $t_{ji} = (1/0.6)(14.43 - 0.8*11.55 ) + (23.09 - 14.43) = 17.3 y$, the same as Jack's time, as expected.

Calculations in frame B are symmetrical of course.

Comment: This is using inertial reference frame A, and is perfectly usable.  But it's not *Jack's* reference frame.  It was initially, but not during and after his turn-around.  The point is you *can* do the computation in Jack's non-inertial frame and get consistent results w/ inertial-frame computations.

Comment: Yes, if there is some information about the accelerated step of the trip. The calculation for a non inertial frame depends on the local acceleration, that are argument of the hyperbolic functions.